# Cooling problems with my ASUS Zenbook pro 15 UX580 after fresh install

Tags: laptop, cpu, cooling, temperature

I recently reinstalled a fresh WIN10 installation on my Zenbook and caught some heating issues. I used the official drivers from the asus site.

The only hardware mortification was an update to the M.2 (I switched to a 1tb ssd), which was handled professionally. I opened and cleaned the vents myself which did not improve the overheating situation.

The Temperature raises to 90°C on normal use and gets to about 50°+ in IDLE in and my office (21°C Ambience Temperature).
Any load makes it nearly impossible to use and I can feel my glass-desk heating up. When I touch the underside of the desk it gets very hot and I need to move my PC to keep it cooler.

Hopefully it will be possible to keep the temperature down when using multiple monitors to work with.

Comment: See if you can get an ASUS Hardware Diagnostics App.  Install and run the App to look for hardware problems.

Comment: Its seems that the MYAsus app is not working correctly on my system.

Comment: Can you ask ASUS Support? This seems to be a hardware issue.

Comment: I will try to reach them, it can also be that the new version of myAsus doesn't like my clean install, the whole APP seems to be broken on my part. (And the reviews on the microsoft store were terrible)

Comment: Yes. Try them.  The heating problems do not appear to be software generated and for the most part, software does not usually cause that level of overheating,